# Preserving changed in resolv.conf across reboots with resolvconf

Tags: resolv.conf, resolvconf

What is the best way to edit the *resolv.conf* file?

I wasn't familiar with setting proxies until a task to configure a server came along.
I manually edited my **/etc/resolv.conf** file and included the following input:

```
nameserver 192.168.115.147,192.178.116.168
```

Any attempt to download was met with errors.
After much googling, I came across a post which led me to reformat the file - directly as follows:

```
nameserver 192.168.115.147
nameserver 192.178.116.168
```

That worked and file downloads were no longer interrupted with errors.

However, when I had to reboot the server the file reverted back to the single line format which again stopped my downloads.
That's when I noticed the `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN` at the top of *resolv.conf*.

**So, how should *resolv.conf* be edited so the changes persist through server reboots?**

Comment: This will depend on the specific vendor, and how their scripts mangle the network configuration. Without knowing the vendor, I'd `fgrep -r 192.168.115.147,192.178.116.168 /etc` to try to find where that specific comma-joined string came from, or look for the vendor's network configuration files (`/etc/network/*`, `/etc/sysconfig/network*`, etc.) to see if DHCP is set, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You use entries in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` named `head`, `base` or `tail` (depending on where in `resolv.conf` you want your entries to come). From [`man resolvconf`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?&query=resolvconf):

```
The dynamically generated resolver  configuration  file always  starts
with  the  contents of /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head and ends with
the contents of /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail.  Between  head  and
tail  the  libc script inserts dynamic nameserver information compiled
from, first, information provided for  configured  interfaces;  second,
static  information  from /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base.
```

Just put your entries in `base` and run `resolvconf -u`.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer**

I think the most reliable way to do that is by setting your `resolv.conf` to be immutable.  Once you set it the way you want, you simply run

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

To edit it again, you need to remove the immutable flag:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Alternate Answer**

The application that puts that message in `/etc/resolv.conf` is called `resolvconf`.  You can remove your `resolvconf` package with (I'm assuming debian or ubuntu here, but I think `resolvconf` is a debian thing):

```
sudo apt-get remove resolvconf
```

I remove it on my computers because I have found that I am more likely to be able to connect with proper `/etc/resolv.conf` settings in strange situations (hotel or airport wifi, specifically) when I do not have the `resolvconf` package installed. `resolvconf` also does other things like DNS caching, and probably some other things I feel I can live without.  You might look into what all it does before you remove it.

**Important notes**

Removing `resolvconf` will not guarantee that your `/etc/resolv.conf` remains unchanged.  Other programs, like `dhclient` will make edits to `/etc/resolv.conf`.  If you run a network manager, that might also edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.  I don't have much experience with network managers.

The `chattr` solution should prevent those other programs from making edits, and is probably right for your server situation.  If you were using it on a laptop, situations may arise where important changes to your `/etc/resolv.conf` would be blocked.  An example would be when accessing hotel wifi, where a modification to your `/etc/resolv.conf` is needed for access to a certain locally hosted url before gain access to the proper internet).  If you can remember in those situations to `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` and reconnect to the wifi, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the network manager that comes with your window server, the simple and proper method to set a persistent DNS nameserver is in your networking config file:

For Debian (Ubuntu, Mint, Arch) edit /etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

dns_nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I believe in Red Hat, Fedora, CentOS, etc. changes to resolve.conf are persistent after reboot.